# como percorrer cada linha de um array de objeto e exibir na tela(PHP)

Tags: php, array, pdo, mvc

Estou com um problema ao exibir uma query(Select) de alguns itens na tela. O mesmo só está exibindo a primeira linha.

```html
<?php
   require_once 'app/Lib/Database/Connection.php';
   require_once 'app/Controller/ImoveisController.php';
   require_once 'app/Model/Imoveis.php';

   $result =  new ImoveisController;
   $row = $result->selectAll();

   var_dump($row);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head> 
    <title>CRUD PHP</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Cod_imovel</th>
          <th>Proprietario</th>
          <th>estado</th> 
          <th>bairro</th>
          <th>municipio</th>
          <th>cep</th>
          <th>numero</th>
          <th>rua</th>
        </tr>

      </thead> 

      <tbody>

      <?php foreach($row as $value):?>

      <td><?php echo $value->i_imoveis?></td>
      <td><?php echo $value->estado ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $value->bairro ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $value->municipio?></td>
      <td><?php echo $value->cep ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $value->numero?></td>
      <td><?php echo $value->rua?></td>
      <?php endforeach;?>
     </tbody>
   </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

model :

```html
<?php
   class Imoveis{
      public static function read(){
        $c = Connection::getConn();
        
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM imoveis";
        $sql = $c->prepare($sql);
        $sql->execute();

        $resultado = array();

        while($row = $sql->fetchObject('Imoveis')){
            $resultado[] = $row;
        }
        if(!$resultado){
            throw new Exception("Não foi encontrado nenhum registro");
        }
        return $resultado;
      }          
   }
?>
```

essa model esta sendo chamada por um controller e até a chamada `$result =  new ImoveisController; $row = $result->selectAll();`  está tudo ok verificando no var_dump, porém ao percorer esse Array do tipo Imóveis com o `

```
   <td><?php echo $value->i_imoveis?></td>
   <td><?php echo $value->estado ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $value->bairro ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $value->municipio?></td>
   <td><?php echo $value->cep ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $value->numero?></td>
   <td><?php echo $value->rua?></td>
   <?php endforeach;?>
  </tbody>`
```

acontece de aparecer somente o primeiro registro

Controller:

```html
<?php
   class ImoveisController{
     public function selectAll(){
        $all =  Imoveis::read();               
        return $all;
     }         
   }
?>
```

Comment: Poderia adicionar na pergunta o método `selectAll` do controlador?

Comment: adicionei a controller

Comment: `var_dump($row);` o que isso exibe?

Comment: Aliás, você percebeu que na sua tabela no HTML não existe os elementos `<tr>`?

Comment: No caso o var_dump estava servindo apenas para verificar se a variavel estava recebendo o valor corretamente. Realmente estava faltando o <tr>. Consegui resolver aqui fazendo da seguinte forma: <?php foreach($row as $value){
       echo "<tr>"; 
       echo "<td>".$value->i_imoveis."</td>";echo "</tr>";

        }?>   desse jeito chamando o html dentro do php e nao o contrario consegui fazer rodar corretamente. Agradeço a ajuda

Comment: O fato do HTML estar no PHP não mudará nada, você está alterando sei código aleatoriamente sem entender o que está fazendo. O problema era só a falta do `<tr>`

Comment: Então acabou que não fui muito claro no antigo comentário, acabei me esquecendo de relatar que aconteceu outro erro. No caso o problema de aparecer apenas a  primeira linha foi resolvido sim com o uso do <tr>, com isso apareceu os demais registros que a variavel estava trazendo, porém o mesmo estava jogando todos os resultados na mesma linha, tentei o uso do </br> porém sem sucesso. Por fim fiz o que comentei antes, fiz a chamada do html dentro da tag do php, ai sim funcionou.

Comment: Pelo que entendi era para funcionar das duas maneiras, porém so funcionou desta forma. Novamente agradeço a ajuda e lamento não ter sido claro. Sou novo por aqui, como posso fechar essa pergunta?